# SQLite cursor selection multiple conditions

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite, conditional-statements

I am trying to pull out rows in the database based on multiple conditions. With code, the condition can be written as

```
if (type == "person" && (name == "John" || name == "David"))
```

Right now I am getting the cursor like so : `type = ? and name = ? or name = ?`

Is this correct? Because I don't know how to express the brackets, I don't want the selection to become: `((type == "person" && name == "John") || name == "David")`

Answer (score 1):

`... Because I don't know how to express the brackets...`
Use the brackets just as you do in Java:

```
SELECT [Field List] FROM [Table Name] WHERE type = ? AND (name = ? OR name = ?)
```